# Remove The Posts or Category Text in NextJS URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How do I remove the 'category' or 'post' from the URL, I use NextJS.

I have searched for tutorials on Google and YouTube but none of them came my way.

So, I want to create a URL like this on NextJS:

> example.com/[category]/[post]

example:

> **example.com/movie**: this page will show all the posts related to the movie.

> **example.com/movie/harry-potter**: and this page features post for Harry Potter specific movies.

As we can see, here there is no 'post' or 'category' text in the URL.

How do I create a URL like that in NextJS?

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem is, but I would recommend you go through the [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) documentation.